# Firebase $authWithOAuthRedirect doesn't call $onAuth without page refresh

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase, angularfire

I have a simple Firebase Facebook OAuth login set like below by following the [official tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/adding-social-login-with-firebase/) for the Ionic Firebase Facebook login.

The problem is that once I click on the login with Facebook button, I get redirected to Facebook, I log in, and I get redirected back to my app. However, the problem is that I stay in the login page. Strange thing is that if I physically refresh my browser (testing with `ionic serve`) by pressing F5 the `onAuth` triggers and I get redirected to the `Items` page. If I don't refresh the browser, `onAuth` doesn't get called.

Did someone have this issue? How did you solve it?

Please note that yes, I did my research (and am slightly starting to lose it), but can't get it to work. I searched SO, tried with [$timeout](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/uoFkZTnHBZg) from google groups, tried to call $scope.$apply(), but all to no avail - so please help me figure out where I'm doing it wrong?

```js
.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, Items, Auth, $state, $ionicHistory) {
    $scope.login = function(provider) {
        Auth.$authWithOAuthRedirect(provider).then(function(authData) {

        }).catch(function(error) {
            if (error.code === "TRANSPORT_UNAVAILABLE") {
                Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(provider).then(function(authData) {
                    
                });
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    };

    $scope.logout = function() {
        Auth.$unauth();
        $scope.authData = null;

        $window.location.reload(true);
    };

    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
        if (authData === null) {
            console.log("Not logged in yet");
            $state.go('app.login');
        } else {
            console.log("Logged in as", authData.uid);
            
            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
              });
            $state.go('app.items');
        }
        $scope.authData = authData; // This will display the user's name in our view
    });
})
```

```html
<ion-view view-title="Members area">
    <ion-content padding="true">
        <div ng-if="!authData">
            <button class="button button-positive button-block" ng-click="login('facebook')">Log In with Facebook</button>  
        </div>       
        
        <div ng-if="authData.facebook">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="item item-text-wrap">Hello {{authData.facebook.displayName}}!</div>                
            </div>

            <button class="button button-assertive button-block" ng-click="logout()">Log out</button>
        </div>        

    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**edit:** I sort of solved it by using $timeout:

```
$timeout(function(){
    Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
        if (authData === null) {
            console.log("Not logged in yet");
            $state.go('app.login');
        } else {
            console.log("Logged in as", authData.uid);

            $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
                disableBack: true
              });
            $state.go('app.items');
        }
        $scope.authData = authData; // This will display the user's name in our view
    });
}, 3000);
```

However, this just feels wrong (mildly put), and there has to be a better way, so please suggest one. Also, I noticed that the whopping 3second delay is barely enough (few of the resources I found suggested 500ms would be enough, but in my case, that's not the case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posted on the github issues, but will reply here as well.

This only happens in the browser using `$authWithOAuthRedirect`. The example was intended for cordova apps, so this really shouldn't be an issue.

But if you really need it, you could just skip the redirect and use a popup.

```
    Auth.$authWithOAuthPopup(authMethod).then(function(authData) {
      console.dir(authData);
    });
```

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! I must have missed this in the docs :/. I thought it was covered actually in the catch block, but it seems it was the other way around. Anyways, thanks, and I just want to personally thank you for the awesome framework! Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 4):

This was a bug that has been fixed in the latest Firebase JS client release ([2.3.0](https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.0/firebase.js)). You can now use `$authWithOAuthRedirect` and the $onAuth callback will be triggered when you navigate back to the page.

Comment: Hey Sara, thank you for the update and the fix. Keep up the good work over at the ever so slightly awesome Firebase!

Comment: Nope, it is still broken.

Comment: any progress with this?